# text not shown on uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have defined a label in my viewController and I also set its `@property` and synthesized it. I have establish link between between file owner and UIlabel in `viewDidLoad`. I am trying to display this string link:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    getname = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    getname.text = @"hello";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

But the string is not displaying on the label on the UIView. Please tell me what I need to do to display a string on a UIView. The view controller and nib file has the same names.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

But when I added `viewcontroller.m` file want to display something on view, it does not response to that code. How can I fix this?

Comment: you using xib? or wants programmatically create label?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just replace this function this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    getname = [[UILabel alloc] init];


    getname.text = @"hello";

    [self.view addSubview:getname];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Hope it helps you..

Also if you are using IBOutlet in your .h file, don't allocate memory to it as it automatically allocates memory.

So if you have used IBOutlet then your function should be

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    getname.text = @"hello";

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `addSubview` if you have an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: but kindly solve my another problem i want to display text in this textfield from a textfield of another viewcontroller that is what i  want to display on the textfield on second view controlelr

Comment: pass values from one view controller to another view controller, while you are presenting second view

Comment: -(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    
    
    nextview *admin = [[nextview alloc]init];
   

    if (admin.view) {
        admin.fetchname = name.text;
    }
     [self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES];
    [admin release];}  i am pasing the value  using button to string in the second viewcontroller and i am assigning that string in secondviewcontroller to getname textfield but value not shown

Comment: -(IBAction)save:(id)sender { nextview *admin = [[nextview alloc]init];  [self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES]; if (admin.view) { admin.fetchname = name.text; } [admin release];} Try this

Comment: for admin viewcontroller, make that text field property, synthesize and then assign text fields values directly

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using a storyboard...**

It sounds like you are using a storyboard, in which case you should remove the `init`, since the storyboard takes care of that for you:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    getname.text = @"hello";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

By using `init` with a storyboard, you are redeclaring the object, so the storyboard can't find it.

**If you are *not* using a storyboard...**

If you are not using a storyboard, then you need to add the label to the view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    getname = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    getname.text = @"hello";
    [self.view addSubview:getname];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

The line `[self.view addSubview:getname];` adds the `UILabel` as a subview so that it actually shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `viewDidLoad` like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    getname.text = @"hello";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

There is no need of allocating an `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 0):

If you added your label in xib then comment the initialization line.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

//getname = [[UILabel alloc] init];


getname.text = @"hello";


[super viewDidLoad];

}
```